# How to save the data using a modal from Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel

I can't save the data taken from textarea in this modal in this laravel form 
This is the code for the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="denyModal_<?= $leave->id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <textarea type="text" name="denied" placeholder="Say something" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
            </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form id="deny-form" action="{{ route('deny_request', $leave->id) }}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
          Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

And this is the `deny_request` from the controller, it should take the value from the textarea named `denied`

```
public function denyRequest(Request $request, $id) {
    $leave = Leave::findOrFail($id);
    $leave->status = 2;
    $leave->denied = $request->input('denied');
    $leave->save();

    return redirect('leaves/'. $request->id .'/edit')->with('success', 'Request Denied!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text area is not inside the form that's why the 'denied' request is not added in your controller function.

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form id="deny-form" action="{{ route('deny_request', $leave->id) }}" method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <textarea type="text" name="denied" placeholder="Say something" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
            </div>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
          Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try textarea inside your form and get textarea inside your controller request